# How to force Node.js to use a predefined IP for a hostname?

Tags: node.js, shell

We are developing a command line tool that relies on a third party Cloud Object Storage SDK, so we cannot modify the request address directly (unless we remade our own SDK based on the official one which is wrong at so many levels). We noticed the IPs resolved by our clients can often be problematic due to their geolocation or DNS provider. So we want to be able to create a "custom host" file if you would say and embed it into the command line tool (npm global module). We look up the DNS documentation and doesn't seem to find relevant information. https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

So basically what we try to do is that one person may resolve `google.com` to `8.7.198.46`, and another person may resolve `google.com` to `74.125.200.139`, instead of letting the DNS do the job we want to force all hostname `google.com` to resolve to a specific IP (let's say 88.88.88.88). How will I be able to do this with Node.js (OR perhaps with the help of an additional shell script)?

Comment: If your usage of the SDK is simple enough, just write your own implementation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1

Comment: It's not even Google's COS to begin with...@Matthew